# Flutter : Play Audio File From Application Directory ( Storage )

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-player

In Stack Overflow or other example, I found that from asset folder and from network I can play audio file easily.

But, There is no clear approach That I can play audio file from Application Storage or mobile device.

My Audio path is :  `String playebleFilePath = '/Users/noorhossain/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5C9813C4-7773-4013-B086-279DB8FCA64F/data/Containers/Data/Application/F905830C-C698-4FEB-80F1-FB386BE18882/Library/Application Support/VocalDatabaseAudio/word_audio_one/2.mp3'`

```
final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
  assetsAudioPlayer.open(
      Audio.file(playebleFilePath),
    );
```

How can I play Audio from this storage path ?

My error log says : `plugin Exception, cannot find the file in this server.`

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is due to the fact that the file you are trying to play is not in the assets folder which will cause the plugin to throw an exception.

i have been using audioplayers plugin and for assets it actually has a prefix to the path that actually points to an "assets" folder, the assets folder should also be correctly referenced in the pubspec.yaml file...

then more importantly since it seems you want to use app directory, consider using something like:`await audioPlayer .play(DeviceFileSource("directory/path to your song"));`

just check out the getting started of the audioplayers library: [ [1]: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md][1]